# Want to remove duplicate symbol error during compile time xcode ios

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

I running my code old code in the latest XCode 13.2 iOS 15 version. While running my application I got the following error,

```
duplicate symbol '__toSelectedDate' in:
    /Users/userName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Administrator-ewwyjnbeieucitgvjwslljnpgsqr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Administrator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Administrator.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BarGraph.o
/Users/userName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Administrator-ewwyjnbeieucitgvjwslljnpgsqr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Administrator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Administrator.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AdherenceOut.o

duplicate symbol '_y_MarkerLblRange' in:
    /Users/userName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Administrator-ewwyjnbeieucitgvjwslljnpgsqr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Administrator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Administrator.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
    /Users/userName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Administrator-ewwyjnbeieucitgvjwslljnpgsqr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Administrator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Administrator.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LoginViewController.o
    
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
        clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have already cleaned my project & removed derived data but not worked. There is no double import or declaration or added in compile sources in xcode build setting.
My code is perfectly runnable on Xcode 10.1 version for iOS 12 version. But apple does not upgrade the build version to upload the build in-app store why I'm stuck to making a compatible code version with the latest iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue using a change in XCode build settings,

```
GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS = YES to NO
```